# Dynamically Updating Bootstrap Popover With AJAX results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have read through many of the questions regarding using AJAX results to update Bootstrap popover content but can't seem to piece together a solution that will work for my situation.  I apologize if I missed something.

I have a series of input boxes in a form in a Modal dialog.  When a certain text box (the #tool box) is filled out and another text box (the #chamber box) comes into focus I send an AJAX call to identify applicable values for the chamber and wish for them to show in the popover.  Using the code below I am able to accomplish this, but only on the first try.  After that, the content remains the same (i.e., is not replaced with the new chamber info).  Note that I am also putting the AJAX results into autocomplete for the input and that changes to the new values every time, just the popover remains the same.

The complexity of the app doesn't lend itself to a jFiddle, below are the applicable snipits

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="chamber">Chamber</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="chamber" name="chamber" type="text" placeholder="Enter a chamber" class="input-xlarge chamberType">
        <a href="#" id="chamberPopup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Chamber in focus:

```
$("#chamber").focus(function() {
    var parent = $('#tool').val();
    if (parent != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getChamberDropdown.php',
            data: {parent: parent},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (chamberResult) {
                var chamberHint;

                if(chamberResult.length > 0) {
                    chamberHint = JSON.stringify(chamberResult);
                } else {
                    chamberHint = "No chambers.";
                }
                $(function () {
                    $('.chamberType').autocomplete({
                        source: chamberResult
                    });
                });

                $('#chamberPopup').popover({
                    placement: "right",
                    html: true,
                    title: "Applicable Chambers",
                    content: chamberHint
                });
            }
        });
        $('#chamberPopup').popover('show');
    }
})
```

Chamber out of focus:

```
$("#chamber").focusout(function() {
    $('#chamberPopup').popover('hide');
})
```

Any advice or assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please adjust your code to the following. Since `popover` does not have a `refresh` method, you would have to `destroy` and re-initialize each time.

```
$(function () {
    var popover = $('#chamberPopup');
    popover.popover();
    $("#chamber").focus(function() {
        popover.popover('destroy').popover({
            placement: "right",
            html: true,
            title: "Applicable Chambers",
            content: 'Loading ..... ... '
        });
        var parent = $('#tool').val();
        if (parent != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getChamberDropdown.php',
                data: {parent: parent},
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (chamberResult) {
                    var chamberHint;

                    if(chamberResult.length > 0) {
                        chamberHint = JSON.stringify(chamberResult);
                    } else {
                        chamberHint = "No chambers.";
                    }
                    $('.chamberType').autocomplete({
                        source: chamberResult
                    });

                    popover.popover('destroy').popover({
                        placement: "right",
                        html: true,
                        title: "Applicable Chambers",
                        content: chamberHint
                    })
                    .popover('show');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help.